# Is it possible to convert a MagSafe 2 connection to MagSafe (original MagSafe 1)?

Tags: magsafe

Is it possible to convert a MagSafe 2 adapter to a MagSafe 1, original, adapter?

Comment: It may be possible, but I've never seen a converter for it.

Comment: I'd also recommend looking at [this](http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/magsafe2-to-magsafe-adapter-the-other-way-around.1424782/) thread.